# Pegar 2 "arrays" numa só linha?

Tags: javascript

Tem por exemplo, como pegar os 2 numa só linha?

Exemplo:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Eu quero pegar o `0` e o `1`

Tem como pegar os 2 juntos, ou terei que criar duas linhas assim;

```
document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");

document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[1].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

?

Comment: Ou isso ou um loop

Comment: a posição do array `[0] e [1]` sempre serão fixas?

Answer (score 3):

Com ES6 podes fazer isso numa só linha assim:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("teste")].forEach(el => el.removeAttribute("disabled"));
```

Mas com JavaScript "antigo" tem de ser com um loop:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("teste");
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[i].removeAttribute("disabled")
}
```

Comment: Em ES6 é uma linha mas também é um loop :)

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, exato :)

Comment: "el" seria o que? Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho o `forEach`passa uma variável à callback que corre para cada elemento. O `el` foi o nome que dei a essa variável e que é um dos elementos com a classe `teste`, um de cada vez.

Comment: Muito bom, mas só é pra habilitar os dois primeiros controles, então você teria que usar um `Array.filter()` ou algo do gênero

Comment: @Wtrmute neste caso não vejo necessidade de usar o `.filter`pois não é preciso dar retorno com uma array com menos elementos filtrados por uma condição.

Comment: @Sergio: Pode ser, mas aqui você está desabilitando _todos_ os controles com a classe `teste`, em vez de só os dois primeiros, como a pergunta pede.

Comment: @Wtrmute não ficou claro para mim que seriam só os dois primeiros elementos mas nesse caso pode usar-se o .slice(0, 1) para reduzir a array.

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve funcionar:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("teste")).map((ele, idx)=> idx === 0 || idx ===1 ?  ele.removeAttribute("disabled") : ele);
```

EDIT:

O método `getElementsByClassName` não retorna um `array`. Então é preciso converte-lo em `array` para essa solucão funcionar. Editei a resposta convertendo pra `array`.